# What about the Kohen?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, birchas-kohanim

It is a given that the Kohen blesses the people, but who blesses the Kohen? Is the Kohen excluded from the Brakha or is he included in the one he makes on the kehillah's behalf?

Comment: The Kohen blesses the people?? ושמו את שמי על בני ישראל **ואני אברכם**. See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20539/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, look four verses back: "you [_kohanim_] shall bless the Jews thusly...".

Comment: @DoubleAA Which translated means, "I will bless *them*".  So the Kohen does the blessing, which causes G-d to bless the people, but what about the Kohen?

Comment: @msh210 RMT: See the link above to the Rambam, who seems to imply the Kohanim are just doing a Mitzva, but God is the only one who blesses.

Comment: @DoubleAA, on the contrary, he calls it a ברכת הדיוט, implying humans are blessing. He does say אין קיבול הברכה תלוי בכהנים (of course) but that doesn't mean they don't bless. (Else he'd be contradicting the _pasuk_ I quoted above.)

Comment: @msh210 An act of blessing which is meaningless if not its value as something God told you to do it is not a contradiction to the pasuk.

Answer (score 7):

Kohanim are blessed by Hashem while the Kohanim bless the people. See Bamidbar Rabbah (end of *parsha* 11):

> מי מברך את הכהנים? תלמוד לומר: ואני אברכם, הכהנים מברכים את ישראל ואני אברך אלו ואלו. הוי, ואני אברכם.‏

Comment: Nice idea. It has a source, too: Bamidbar Rabbah (end of *parsha* 11). \[Available in [pdf](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&st=&pgnum=80) or [plain-text](http://daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=4&perek=6&mefaresh=raba).]